# VBA Finding an offset cell based on the value selected in a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a two worksheet workbook.  SheetA contains ComboBoxes that are populated from ranges on SheetB.

So `Combobox1.ListFillRange = SheetB!$A$2:$A$5`

On SheetB Column B would contain a related integer IE:

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
|  Value1  |     5    |
+----------+----------+
|  Value2  |     7    |
+----------+----------+
|  Value3  |    12    |
+----------+----------+
|  Value 4 |    32    |
+----------+----------+
```

If the user selects Value2 from ComboBox1... I need to look up the value in SheetB!$B$3:$B$3 which would be 7 in this example.

I am trying to figure out code that I can place here:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

To do the job.

Thanks for the help I have 6 hours of non-billable time sunk into trying to make this work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Place this in the code behind `SheetA`

Use the value of `MyValue` as you need

This uses the `ListFillRange` property of the ComboBox to reference the sheet and range the ComboBox data is drawn from

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyValue As Variant
    Dim ListRange As String
    Dim i As Long

    ListRange = ComboBox1.ListFillRange
    i = InStr(ListRange, "!")
    If i Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Left$(ListRange, i - 1))
    Else
        Set ws = Me
    End If
    MyValue = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, ws.Range(ListRange).Resize(, 2), 2, 0)

    Debug.Print MyValue

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This solution worked perfectly.  So nice to be able to start my Friday on a positive note.